# Find i-frame macroblock data of MPEG file using C#

Tags: c#, video, byte, mpeg

I try to find i-frame macroblock data and then do some XOR processing. using filestream read and write i read some mpeg file and after find i-frame i change bit data of them using XOR. last write to new file.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open);
        FileStream fscreate = new FileStream(textBox2.Text, FileMode.Create);
        long size = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text).Length;

        byte[] mybyte = new byte[size];
        Console.WriteLine("start read");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            mybyte[i] = (byte) fs.ReadByte(); 
            // if mybyte[i] is i-frame byte. do XOR;
        }

        fscreate.Write(mybyte, 0, mybyte.Length);

        fs.Dispose();
        fscreate.Dispose();
    }
```